# Prove that if $X$ is finite then $f[X]$ is finite for any function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $|f[X]|\le |X|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory, cardinals

First of all I point out that if $X$ and $Y$ are two sets then the set $Y^X$ is the set of all function from $X$ to $Y$.

So in the text *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech it is proved the following alternative version of the recursion theorem.

> **Theorem 3.5**
>
> For any set $S$ and any function $g:\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}S^n\rightarrow S$ there exists a unique sequence $f:\Bbb N\rightarrow S$ such that
> $$
> f(n)=g(f|_n)
> $$
> for all $n\in\Bbb N$

So using this result the same text proves that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function defined in a finite set then its immage $f[X]$ is finite too.

> **Theorem 2.5**
>
> If $X$ is a finite set and $f$ is a function, the $f[X]$ is finite. Moreover, $|f[X]|\le|X| $
>
> *Proof*. Let $X=\{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$. Again, we use recursion to construct a finite one-to-one sequence whose range is $f[X]$. Actually, here we use the version with $f(n+1)=g(f|_n)$. We ask the reader to supply the details; the construction goes as follows:
> $$
> k_0:=0\\
> k_{i+1}:=\min\{k\in(k_i,n):f(x_k)\neq f(x_{k_j})\,\forall j\le i\}\,\,\text{provided it exists}
> $$
> so tha tif $y_i=f(x_{k_i})$ then
> $$
> f[X]=\{y_0,\dots,y_{m-1}\}
> $$
> for some $m\le n$

So unfortunately I did not able to use the theorem $3.5$ to prove the theorem $2.5$ so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask to show how use it. So could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to delete and repost instead of editing?

Comment: I figured if I only edited the question then few people would see it.

Comment: Why is that? You do know that editing a question will bump it up to the front page. Right?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I thought that by rewriting the question and answering it, more people would see it. Maybe I have committed an infraction? I apologize in that case.

Comment: Yes, in the future use the edit feature. It's there for a reason.

Comment: Okay. Anyway could you help me to prove the theorem 2.5?